# plot phylogenetic logistic regression with binary response variable

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression, phylogeny

I used the [phylolm](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=phylolm) package to do phylogenetic comparative analysis. As my response variable is binary data (ones and zeros), I used phylogenetic logistic regression.

How do I plot the output of `phyloglm`? I found a similar question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/2dslgq/fitting_a_regression_curve_from_the_output_of/), but I can't understand the reply. could you please provide some advice about how to plot the results, as shown here?
[image: pls]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the example from `?phyloglm`:

```
library(ape)
library(phylolm)
set.seed(123456)
tre = rtree(50)
x = rTrait(n=1,phy=tre)
X = cbind(rep(1,50),x)
y = rbinTrait(n=1,phy=tre, beta=c(-1,0.5), alpha=1 ,X=X)
dat = data.frame(trait01 = y, predictor = x)
fit = phyloglm(trait01~predictor,phy=tre,data=dat,boot=100)
```

Plot (jittered) data and response (`plogis()` is the logistic function.
The predicted value is `logistic(a+b*x)`; we use `curve()` with
`add=TRUE` to draw the line)

```
par(las=1,bty="l") ## cosmetic
plot(x,jitter(y,factor=0,amount=0.02),
     xlab="trait",ylab="response",xlim=c(-3.5,3.5))
cc <- coef(fit)
curve(plogis(cc[1]+cc[2]*x),col="red",add=TRUE)
```

[image]

The OP's version of this plot is

[image]

which (although we can't see the y-axis scale) is perfectly consistent with a logistic fit, being approximately linear across the intermediate range of predicted values (there is a hint of deceleration at the upper end of the curve).

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot for this quick help! I run the code, it worked. However, the regression line I obtained is a linear line, not like the line you obtained.  I don't know how to uplpoad pic in comment, and I googled and found the pic in this website is quite similar as my pic. http://www.bzst.com/2012/05/linear-regression-for-binary-outcome-is.html.

Comment: hard to say, but your logistic regression curve will be *approximately* linear if the predicted probabilities are (approximately) between 0.3 and 0.7.  You can upload images to imgur if you like and include the link in your comment, *or* edit your question ...

Comment: Sorry, I can not upload two pics in my question, hence, I used my google drive to store the pic:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5VHYG-mRtCUTk1qdTJlZk9mYkE/view?usp=sharing. Many thanks!

Comment: Your plot looks fine.

Comment: Great help! Thanks a lot, Ben! Sorry for the missing of X axis. It is the same as your plot, from 0 to 1. I got what your meaning, and thanks again for the help with the question and the edits of the question!

Comment: Hi! Can anyone recommend a way to get the uncertainty around the model's prediction?