# How to plot slopes for factor levels, with confidence bands, using model-averaged coefficients? (PGLS, Phylogenetic Least Squares)

Tags: r, visualization, confidence-interval, phylogeny, mumin

I am using Phylogenetic Least Squares models, fitted with the `phylolm` package, to understand the effect of continuous and categorical variables. I used the `MuMIn` package to gel model-averaged coefficients, and my response was log-transformed.

**How do I visualize slopes for multiple factor levels, with confidence bands, using model-averaged coefficients?** My aim is a plot that combines the raw data, and the slopes for each factor level (in other words, to visualize two effects in a single plot).

I would normally rely on `predict(se.fit = TRUE)` or the `ggpredict` package, but unfortunately, [these methods are not compatible with model-averaged `phylolm` objects](https://github.com/lamho86/phylolm/issues/67).

Therefore, I am thinking on relying on model-averaged coefficients, standard errors / confidence intervals. In particular, my model has 3 levels, and a common slope (the reprex below has significant differences among factor levels, but it serves to illustrate my doubts).

From previous SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225223/geom-abline-for-logistic-regression-ggplot2?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441467/plot-phylogenetic-logistic-regression-with-binary-response-variable)), I've got an idea about how to plot slopes when there is a transformation: inverse.function(intercept + slope * variable).

However, I am stumped when it comes to visualizing the uncertainty around the slopes for multiple factor levels. **For instance, if using the method of +/- 1.96 * Standard error, how should I take into account the uncertainty around the factor level and the slope?** In the reprex below I only used the standard error of the intercept and each factor level. A similar doubt would apply if relying on confidence intervals.

Note that in the reprex below, `phylolm` is loaded before `MuMIn`, this is needed for compatibility of `logLik` method (https://github.com/lamho86/phylolm/issues/65).

```r
library(caper)
#> Warning: package 'caper' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Loading required package: ape
#> Warning: package 'ape' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Loading required package: MASS
#> Loading required package: mvtnorm
#> Warning: package 'mvtnorm' was built under R version 4.1.1
library(phylolm)
#> Warning: package 'phylolm' was built under R version 4.1.3
library(MuMIn)
#> Warning: package 'MuMIn' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'MuMIn':
#>   method         from   
#>   nobs.pgls      caper  
#>   nobs.phylolm   phylolm
#>   logLik.phylolm phylolm
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 4.1.3

## Create data
data(shorebird)
shorebird.data$M.Mass.std <- (shorebird.data$M.Mass - mean(shorebird.data$M.Mass))/sd(shorebird.data$M.Mass)
str(shorebird.data)
#> 'data.frame':    71 obs. of  7 variables:
#>  $ Species   : chr  "Actophilornis_africanus" "Aphriza_virgata" "Arenaria_interpres" "Arenaria_melanocephala" ...
#>  $ M.Mass    : num  143 186 108 114 151 ...
#>  $ F.Mass    : num  261 216 113 124 164 ...
#>  $ Egg.Mass  : num  8.6 22.4 17.9 17.3 23.5 11.2 10.7 9.6 19.3 13.3 ...
#>  $ Cl.size   : num  4 4 3.5 4 3.99 3.9 3.9 4 3.7 3.9 ...
#>  $ Mat.syst  : Factor w/ 3 levels "MO","PA","PG": 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ M.Mass.std: num  -0.1658 0.0666 -0.3557 -0.3255 -0.1238 ...
str(shorebird.tree)
#> List of 4
#>  $ edge       : num [1:132, 1:2] 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 79 80 ...
#>  $ edge.length: num [1:132] 18.1 13.4 13.4 2.6 2.3 ...
#>  $ tip.label  : chr [1:71] "Catoptrophorus_semipalmatus" "Tringa_ochropus" "Tringa_stagnatilis" "Tringa_flavipes" ...
#>  $ Nnode      : num 62
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "phylo"
#>  - attr(*, "origin")= chr "/Users/dorme/Scripts/CAIC/caic/pkg/data/shorebird.nex"

## Fit model
mod <- phylolm::phylolm(log(Egg.Mass) ~ M.Mass.std + Mat.syst, data = shorebird.data, phy = shorebird.tree, model = "lambda")


## Model average
options(na.action = "na.fail")
mod.d <- MuMIn::dredge(mod, rank = "AICc")
#> Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
mod.avg <- MuMIn::model.avg(mod.d, revised.var = TRUE, fit = TRUE)

# Coefficients and model-averaged confidence intervalss
summary(mod.avg)$coefmat.full
#>               Estimate Std. Error   z value   Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept)  2.9477111 0.24188761 12.186284 0.00000000
#> M.Mass.std   0.4704710 0.05739476  8.197107 0.00000000
#> Mat.systPA  -0.2154969 0.09765281  2.206766 0.02733044
#> Mat.systPG   0.2837279 0.17353949  1.634947 0.10206008

# Keep coefficients
intercept <- summary(mod.avg)$coefmat.full[1, 1]
slope <- summary(mod.avg)$coefmat.full[2, 1]
level.pa <- summary(mod.avg)$coefmat.full[3, 1]
level.pg <- summary(mod.avg)$coefmat.full[4, 1]

# Keep standard errors
intercept.std <- summary(mod.avg)$coefmat.full[1, 2]
slope.std <- summary(mod.avg)$coefmat.full[2, 2]
level.pa.std <- summary(mod.avg)$coefmat.full[3, 2]
level.pg.std <- summary(mod.avg)$coefmat.full[4, 2]


# Slopes at the response scale, from model-averaged coefficients
seq.x <- seq(min(shorebird.data$M.Mass.std), max(shorebird.data$M.Mass.std), by = 0.05)
slope.mo <- exp(intercept + slope * seq.x)
slope.pa <- exp(intercept + level.pa + slope * seq.x)
slope.pg <- exp(intercept + level.pg + slope * seq.x)

# Uncertainty around slope, from model-averaged standard errors
uncert.mo.low <- exp(intercept + slope * seq.x - 1.96 * intercept.std)
uncert.mo.up <- exp(intercept + slope * seq.x + 1.96 * intercept.std)
uncert.pa.low <- exp(intercept + level.pa + slope * seq.x - 1.96 * level.pa.std)
uncert.pa.up <- exp(intercept + level.pa + slope * seq.x + 1.96 * level.pa.std)
uncert.pg.low <- exp(intercept + level.pg + slope * seq.x - 1.96 * level.pg.std)
uncert.pg.up <- exp(intercept + level.pg + slope * seq.x + 1.96 * level.pg.std)


ggplot() + 
  geom_jitter(data = shorebird.data, aes(x = M.Mass.std, y = Egg.Mass, col = Mat.syst)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = seq.x, y = slope.mo), col = "red") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = seq.x, y = slope.mo, ymin = uncert.mo.low, ymax = uncert.mo.up), fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = seq.x, y = slope.pa), col = "green") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = seq.x, y = slope.pa, ymin = uncert.pa.low, ymax = uncert.pa.up), fill = "green", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = seq.x, y = slope.pg), col = "blue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = seq.x, y = slope.pg, ymin = uncert.pg.low, ymax = uncert.pg.up), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
confint(mod.avg, full = TRUE)
#>                   2.5 %      97.5 %
#> (Intercept)  2.47362007  3.42180208
#> M.Mass.std   0.35797932  0.58296266
#> Mat.systPA  -0.40689283 -0.02410087
#> Mat.systPG  -0.05640321  0.62385908
  

sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
#> [5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.1     purrr_1.0.1    
#>  [5] readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.3.0     tibble_3.2.1    ggplot2_3.4.2  
#>  [9] tidyverse_1.3.1 MuMIn_1.46.0    phylolm_2.6.2   caper_1.0.1    
#> [13] mvtnorm_1.1-3   MASS_7.3-54     ape_5.6-2      
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3       lubridate_1.8.0    lattice_0.20-44    listenv_0.8.0     
#>  [5] assertthat_0.2.1   digest_0.6.29      utf8_1.2.2         parallelly_1.31.1 
#>  [9] cellranger_1.1.0   R6_2.5.1           backports_1.4.1    reprex_2.0.1      
#> [13] stats4_4.1.0       evaluate_0.15      httr_1.4.2         highr_0.9         
#> [17] pillar_1.9.0       rlang_1.1.0        readxl_1.4.0       rstudioapi_0.13   
#> [21] Matrix_1.3-3       rmarkdown_2.13     labeling_0.4.2     munsell_0.5.0     
#> [25] broom_0.8.0        modelr_0.1.8       compiler_4.1.0     xfun_0.30         
#> [29] pkgconfig_2.0.3    globals_0.15.0     htmltools_0.5.2    tidyselect_1.2.0  
#> [33] codetools_0.2-18   fansi_1.0.3        future_1.25.0      crayon_1.5.1      
#> [37] tzdb_0.3.0         dbplyr_2.1.1       withr_2.5.0        grid_4.1.0        
#> [41] jsonlite_1.8.0     nlme_3.1-152       gtable_0.3.0       lifecycle_1.0.3   
#> [45] DBI_1.1.2          magrittr_2.0.3     scales_1.2.0       future.apply_1.9.0
#> [49] cli_3.6.0          stringi_1.7.6      farver_2.1.0       fs_1.5.2          
#> [53] xml2_1.3.3         ellipsis_0.3.2     generics_0.1.2     vctrs_0.6.1       
#> [57] tools_4.1.0        glue_1.6.2         hms_1.1.1          parallel_4.1.0    
#> [61] fastmap_1.1.0      yaml_2.3.5         colorspace_2.0-3   rvest_1.0.2       
#> [65] knitr_1.38         haven_2.5.0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>